# Memcache delete: Unknown exception deleting key

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to determine if its possible to find out the cause of an exception we occasionally get when using Google App Engine's Memcache.

The documentation states that if the key doesn't exist it returns false, so I believe the error indicates a different issue.

This is the stack trace of the error we are getting:

```
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.LogAndContinueErrorHandler handleServiceError: Service error in memcache (LogAndContinueErrorHandler.java:49)
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache delete: Unknown exception deleting key: ahBzfmlkZXh4LXNlcnZpY2Vzch0LEgdQYXRpZW50GICA6ODn6-ELDAsSA0pvYhgBDA
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler.handleApiProxyException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.absorbParentException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.handleParentException(FutureWrapper.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.delete(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:125)
```

Here is some relevant code:

```
boolean putValue = memcacheService.put(syncKey, syncKey, Expiration.byDeltaMillis(60000), MemcacheService.SetPolicy.ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT);

memcacheService.delete(syncKey, 100L);
```

Later requests are unable to put the same key indicating that the object still exists. Given that I am specifying a 60 second expiration, I'd expect that it'd be available after that time, but it's not the case. Right now, the only way we've found to fix this is to clear the entire Memcache.